# Free alternative to Lighthouse Code Coverage Explorer?

Tags: ida, radare2, ghidra

I was trying to find if there is any free tool that allows an output similar to [Lighthouse](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse). I want to highlight the code paths taken so that I only reverse engineer the parts that are being executed. Unfortunately, Lighthouse only plugs into IDA Pro and Binary Ninja paid versions.

Perhaps there is a free plugin for Ghidra or radare2/Cutter?

If such a plugin is not available, how can I go about making something like that? What would be the basic building blocks?

Answer (score 3):

I found some tools for both the open source software products.

Ghidra:

- [Dragon Dance](https://github.com/0ffffffffh/dragondance)
- [EMERALD](https://github.com/reb311ion/emerald)

Cutter:

- [CutterDRcov](https://github.com/oddcoder/CutterDRcov)